# Extracting value of xml in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing, xmltable

Please tell me how to extract the guid field from this XML? The problem is the presence of xmlns parameters. Currently returning empty.

```
with XML_text(col) as
(
select
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<purchasePlan
xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/purchasePlan/1"
xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/types/1"
xmlns:ns10="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/decisionSuspension/1"
xmlns:ns11="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/disagreementProtocol/1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://zakupki.gov.ru/223/integration/schema/TFF-13.1 https://zakupki.gov.ru/223/integration/schema/TFF-13.1/purchasePlan.xsd">
<body>
<item>
<guid>096c4bf6-d656-4441-9032-0b7c45423af1</guid>
</item>
</body>
</purchasePlan>'::xml
)
SELECT r.guid
  FROM XML_text as x,
       XMLTABLE('purchasePlan/body/item' passing x.col
                COLUMNS guid varchar(50) path './guid'
                ) as r
;
```

The result must be '096c4bf6-d656-4441-9032-0b7c45423af1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has a default namespace. All XML elements are bound to it, even if we don't see it explicitly. It needs to be declared via `xmlnamespaces(...)` clause and used in the XPath expressions.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jQP5cGtF)

**SQL**

```
with XML_text(col) as
(
select
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<purchasePlan xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/purchasePlan/1"
              xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/types/1"
              xmlns:ns10="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/decisionSuspension/1"
              xmlns:ns11="http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/disagreementProtocol/1"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://zakupki.gov.ru/223/integration/schema/TFF-13.1 https://zakupki.gov.ru/223/integration/schema/TFF-13.1/purchasePlan.xsd">
    <body>
        <item>
            <guid>096c4bf6-d656-4441-9032-0b7c45423af1</guid>
        </item>
    </body>
</purchasePlan>'::xml
)
SELECT r.guid
  FROM XML_text as x,
       XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://zakupki.gov.ru/223fz/types/1' AS "ns1"),
                '/ns1:purchasePlan/ns1:body/ns1:item' 
                PASSING x.col
                COLUMNS guid varchar(50) path 'ns1:guid'
                ) as r
;
```